# Variation of the sum of absolute values of coefficients for shifted Chebyshev polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials

## Setting

Let $\rho \in ]0,1[$, $\varepsilon\in[0,\rho]$,  $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$ and
$$P^\varepsilon_k(X) = \tfrac{T_k\left(\tfrac{2(X+\varepsilon)}{\rho+\varepsilon}-1 \right)}{\left|T_k\left(\tfrac{2(1+\varepsilon)}{\rho+\varepsilon}-1 \right) \right|},$$
a shifted Chebyshev polynomial on $[-\varepsilon,\rho]$,
where $T_k$ is the Chebyshev polynomial of first kind with degree $k$, i.e. $T_k(\cos(\theta)) = \cos(k\theta),\; \forall \theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

## Problem

I would like to show that the function $\varepsilon \rightarrow \| P^\varepsilon_k \|_1$ (with $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the sum of the absolute value of the polynomial's coefficients) is decreasing on $[0,\rho]$. It is true for $\varepsilon$ near $0$ and seems true numerically for all $\varepsilon\in[0,+\infty[$.

## First result

#### Case $\varepsilon$ close to 0

We have from the definition of $T_k$ that its roots are the $(z_i)_{i\in[0 ,k-1]} = (\cos\left(\tfrac{2i+1}{2k}\pi \right))_{i\in[0 ,k-1]} \in [-1,1]$. The roots of $P^\varepsilon_k(X)$ are the $z^\varepsilon_i$ defined such that $\tfrac{2z^\varepsilon_i+2\varepsilon}{\rho+\varepsilon} -1 = z_i $. This corresponds to
$$ z^\varepsilon_i = \tfrac{(\rho+\varepsilon)z_i + \rho - \varepsilon}{2} \in [-\varepsilon,\rho], \quad i=0,\dots,k-1.$$
The smallest root $z^\varepsilon_{k-1} = \tfrac{(\rho+\varepsilon)\cos(\tfrac{2k-1}{2k}\pi) + \rho - \varepsilon}{2}$ is nonnegative for $\varepsilon\in[0,\rho\tfrac{1+\cos(\tfrac{2k-1}{2k}\pi)}{1-\cos(\tfrac{2k-1}{2k}\pi)}]$. This means that this for choice of $\varepsilon$, all the roots of $P^\varepsilon_k$ are nonnegative and therefore coefficients of $P^\varepsilon_k$ alternate signs (we see that by expressing the coefficients using the roots). This fact implies that one can write $\| P^\varepsilon_k\|_1 = \left | P^\varepsilon_k(-1) \right|$ which can be expressed as
\begin{align*}
    \left | P^\varepsilon_k(-1) \right| &= \tfrac{\left|T_k\left(\tfrac{2(-1+\varepsilon)}{\rho+\varepsilon} -1\right)\right|}{T_k\left(\tfrac{2(1+\varepsilon)}{\rho+\varepsilon} -1\right)}\\
    & = \tfrac{\left(1 +\tfrac{\rho-\varepsilon}{2} -\sqrt{(1+\rho)(1-\varepsilon)}\right)^k +\left(1 +\tfrac{\rho-\varepsilon}{2} +\sqrt{(1+\rho)(1-\varepsilon)}\right)^k}{\left(1 +\tfrac{\rho-\varepsilon}{2} -\sqrt{(1-\rho)(1+\varepsilon)}\right)^k +\left(1 +\tfrac{\rho-\varepsilon}{2} +\sqrt{(1-\rho)(1+\varepsilon)}\right)^k},
\end{align*}
where we use the formula $T_k(x) = \tfrac{1}{2}\left(\left(x - \sqrt{x^2-1} \right)^k+\left(x + \sqrt{x^2-1} \right)^k \right)$ for $|x| \geq 1$. Finally, a simple study of function shows that the numerator is decreasing and the denominator increasing.

#### Additional info

Note that $P^\varepsilon_k$ is solution of the optimization problem
$$ \underset{\substack{p\in\mathbf{R}_k[X]\\p(1)=1}}{\min}\underset{x\in[-\varepsilon,\rho]}{\max}|p(x)|. $$

Any ideas or pointers are welcome, thanks for your help.